# Python for-loop with modification of the iterationlist

Tags: python

I have this .txt file:

```
king james version of the bible   
the first book of moses  called genesis
```

I use a python-script for statistics on .txt files, the file is read into the list `final_list` and then I execute this code (part of longer script):

```
for word in final_list:
    output_list.append((word,final_list.count(word)))

    final_list[:] = [x for x in final_list if x != word]
    #DEBUGGING
    print(len(final_list))
    print(final_list)
```

My problem is that some of my list is not used by the for-loop, which I suspect form looking at the output:

```
12
['james', 'version', 'of', 'the', 'bible', 'the', 'first', 'book', 'of', 'moses', 'called', 'genesis']
11
['james', 'of', 'the', 'bible', 'the', 'first', 'book', 'of', 'moses', 'called', 'genesis']
9
['james', 'of', 'bible', 'first', 'book', 'of', 'moses', 'called', 'genesis']
8
['james', 'of', 'bible', 'book', 'of', 'moses', 'called', 'genesis']
6
['james', 'bible', 'book', 'moses', 'called', 'genesis']
5
['james', 'bible', 'book', 'moses', 'called']
```

This makes me wonder how the python for-loop actually works.

Comment: Your code is a very inefficient way of counting word frequencies.  Have a look at `collections.Counter()`, which will do the job for you both easier and much faster.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Still I guess this is not the problem with the last 5 words not being iterated, right?

Comment: Never change a list you are iterating over. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: I will think of it - was somewhat fishy from the start. Though the idea came from SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you're modifying the list. After the first iteration, Python's iterator stops looking at "position 0" in the list and moves to "position 1." You removed the element originally in position 0 (`king`), so the element that used to be in position 1 (`james`) is now in position 0, which means that when Python looks at the element in position 1, it sees the element that was originally in position 2 (`version`).

At the end, Python's iterator has moved to a position that is beyond the end of the list, so it quits in a manner you think is premature, even though that is precisely what you've asked it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify the list you are iterating on inside the for loop. Otherwise you will get this kind of weird behavior. You'd better use a copy of the final_list likeso:

```
final_copy = final_list[:]
for word in final_list:
     output_list.append((word,final_copy.count(word)))
     final_copy = [x for x in final_copy if x != word]
```

Comment: Fine, though this way there will be multiple instances of multiple words in `output_list`.